# Get Azure Databricks lineage components

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, azure-notebooks

Usually In data bricks we will have workspace and then notebooks. Inside notebooks we will have commands. I will get these commands one by one and based on this each command I have to prepare lineage. For building lineage we need source and destination so how can we get source and destination using this command
For Example:
**%python
display(dbutils.fs.ls("/databricks-datasets"))**
Above is one command so how can we figure source and destination. I know using Spline tool we can get the solution but we need to work on commands.
So can anyone help me on this